# What in this IndexedDB code is causing the device storage to fill up to 1.6GB?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

Our application that utilizes IndexedDB to track tallies of data over periods of time. In using the app for a number of months, it seems that there is some sort of storage leak causing a relatively small amount of data to require 1.6 GB of storage on the device?

[image: Chrome storage report showing app using 1.6GB of data]

The app has a feature to download its full data as a ZIP file, and that file is under **50KB.** So there must be a long-term leak somewhere. What we're trying now is to download the data, clear storage, and re-import to track down where this leak might be.

However, looking at the following code that interacts with IndexedDB, it's not obvious to me where that leak may be:

```js
// Initializing the Database

if(!dbengine){
  dbengine = this;
  var request = window.indexedDB.open("DB", 1);

  request.onerror = function(event) {
    throw new Error("Error opening indexedDb")
  };

  // This creates the schema the first time around
  request.onupgradeneeded = (event) => {
    event.target.result.createObjectStore("db", { keyPath: 'id' });
  };

  request.onsuccess = (event) => {
    dbengine.db = event.target.result;
    var dbReadyEvent = new CustomEvent('db-ready', {});
    document.dispatchEvent(dbReadyEvent);

    dbengine.db.onerror = function(event) {
      throw new Error("Database error: " + event.target.errorCode);
    };

    dbengine.db.onabort = function(event) {
      throw new Error("Database aborted: " + event.target.error);
      // This is the error that is being called for us - QuotaExceededError
    };
  };
}// if !dbengine



var initialTransaction = dbengine.db.transaction(['db'], 'readwrite');

initialTransaction.onabort = (event) => {
  var error = event.target.error; // DOMError
  alert(error.name);
} // onabort

initialTransaction.objectStore('db').openCursor().onsuccess = (event) => {
  var cursor = event.target.result;
  if(cursor) {
    this.encryption.loadIdentity((success) => {
      if(success) {
        this.loadDb(() => {
          document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('api-ready', {}));
          setInterval(this.syncDb.bind(this), this.syncInterval);
          this.syncDb();
        });
      } else {
        document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('api-fail', {}));
      }
    });
  } else {
    initialTransaction.objectStore('db').add({
      /* [...] */
    });

    document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('db-created', {}));
  } // if/else cursor
}; // objectStore

loadDb(callback) {
  this._tallies = [];
  this._collections = [];

  var dbStore = dbengine.db.transaction(['db'], 'readwrite').objectStore('db');
  dbStore.get(1).onsuccess = (event) => {
    var result = event.target.result;

    var tallies = result.tallies;
    if(result.tallies.length !== 0) {
      tallies = this._encryption.decrypt(result.tallies);
    }

    tallies.forEach(((t) => {
      /* [...] */
    }));

    var collections = result.collections;
    if(collections.length !== 0) {
      collections = this._encryption.decrypt(result.collections);
    }

    collections.forEach(((c) => {
      /* [...] */
    }));

    callback()
  }
} // loadDb



logout() {
  var dbStore = dbengine.db.transaction(['db'], 'readwrite').objectStore('db');

  var request = dbStore.get(1);

  request.onsuccess = function(e) {
    delete e.currentTarget.result.identity;
    dbStore.put(e.currentTarget.result);
    redirectTo('welcome');
  };
} // logout

syncDb() {
  var tallyDataString = JSON.stringify(this.tallies);
  var collectionDataString = JSON.stringify(this.collections);
  var encryptedTallyDataString = this._encryption.encrypt(tallyDataString);
  var encryptedCollectionDataString = this._encryption.encrypt(collectionDataString);

  var dbStore = dbengine.db.transaction(['db'], 'readwrite').objectStore('db');

  dbStore.get(1).onsuccess = (event) => {
    var data = event.target.result;
    if(data.tallies !== encryptedTallyDataString) {
      data.tallies = encryptedTallyDataString;
      dbStore.put(data);
    }

    if(data.collections !== encryptedCollectionDataString) {
      data.collections = encryptedCollectionDataString;
      dbStore.put(data);
    }

    var syncEvent = new CustomEvent('sync', {});
    document.dispatchEvent(syncEvent);
  } // onsuccess

  dbStore.get(1).onabort = (event) => {
    var error = event.target.error; // DOMError
    // if (error.name == 'QuotaExceededError') {
    //   alert('Sync failed. Quota exceeded.')
    // }
    alert(error.name);
  } // onabort
} // syncDb

loadIdentity(callback) {
  var dbStore = dbengine.db.transaction(['db'], 'readwrite').objectStore('db');
  dbStore.get(1).onsuccess = (event) => {
    var result = event.target.result;

    if(!result.identity || !result.identity.publicKey || !result.identity.privateKey) {
      if(window.location.pathname !== "/app/welcome/")  {
        redirectTo('welcome');
      }
    }

    this.identity = {
      /* [...] */
    };

    var solid = false;
    if(result.identity.publicKey && result.identity.privateKey) {
      solid = true;
    }

    callback(solid);
  };
  } // loadIdentity

  setIdentity(identity, username) {
  var dbStore = dbengine.db.transaction(['db'], 'readwrite').objectStore('db');
  var getRequest = dbStore.get(1);

  getRequest.onsuccess = (event) => {
    var result = event.target.result;

    result.identity = {
      /* [...] */
    };

    this.identity = identity;
    var request = dbStore.put(result);
  } // getRequest
} // setIdentity
```

Comment: Can you file a bug against Chrome using https://crbug.com so the developers can take a look? You might be running into a browser bug. (We recently identified a leak with blobs; it's unclear if your code is using blobs for the data chunks or inline data)

Comment: @JoshuaBell Thank you for your comment. It looks like exactly the issue described here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=757142&q=indexeddb&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified and here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=756754&q=indexeddb&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&desc=2

Comment: @JoshuaBell Though, I don't know if I'm using blobs or not. Am I? How can I find that out?

Comment: @JoshuaBell Finally, is there a workaround? :)

Comment: Blobs would be explicitly created either via `new Blob()` or `new File()` or the results of fetching via XMLHttpRequest or `fetch()`. 

No workaround unfortunately.